# How to use jQuery and JavaScript accurately find if an element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've read several posts about this but it simply does not work for me. I'm using Ruby on Rails as my MVC framework. I add classes to my body tag mapping to the `controller` and `action`.

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
```

So on a controller `home` action `about` I might have

```
<body class="home about">
```

Rendered by the server and sent to the client. I want to have page specific JavaScript but I can't seem to do it correctly.

### I've tried this but it always returns true

```
var page = $('body.home')

if (page) {
  console.log('Right page')
} else {
  console.log('Wrong page');
}

// returns 
// jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "body.information"]
```

### I've tried this but it always returns true

```
var page = $('body.home')[0]

if (page) {
  console.log('Right page')
} else {
  console.log('Wrong page');
}
```

### I've tried this but it always returns true

```
var page = $('body.home')[0]

if ($(page)) {
  console.log('Right page')
} else {
  console.log('Wrong page');
}
```

### I've tried this but it always returns false

```
var page = $('body.home')[0]

if ($(page).length > 0) {
  console.log('Right page')
} else {
  console.log('Wrong page');
}
```

So when I'm on the correct page(a page with element body that has class home) it `console.logs` 'Wrong page'

Comment: `$('body.home').length`

Comment: This doesn't work either =(

Answer (score 1):

To check for a class, you need to use classList.

Like so:

Plain javascript.(classList.contains only works in mordern browsers);

```js
 let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    console.log(body[0].classList.contains('one'));
    console.log(body[0].classList.contains('two'));
```

```html
<body class="one tow">
</body>
```

You can also do:

```js
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')
let isClassThree = body[0].className.split(" ").indexOf('three')
let isClassFour = body[0].className.split(" ").indexOf('four')
console.log(isClassThree, isClassFour)
```

```html
<body class='two three'>
</body>
```

JQuery: `$("body").hasClass(className)`

Comment: I'm getting a complaint of `Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined`
http://prntscr.com/i32pir

Comment: Update it to: body[0].classList.contains(className). I missed that getElements returns an array

Comment: I just did the update. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly, but it seems like it doesn't understand classList?
http://prntscr.com/i32qsa

Comment: Thanks for your help either way!

Comment: It's so weird, it keeps complaining about classList. http://prntscr.com/i32tz9.

But it works in the console. Let me play around with it and I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Updated my answer to yet another implementation, see if that helps. Otherwise, share some exact code that you are using.